# Preferred network mode falls back to 3G from 2G

Tags: android, android-source, gsm, android-networking, android-settings

I am working on Preferred Network Mode Settings in AOSP code. I have to change the network mode to 4g, 3g or 2g based on selection from the UI without switching on/off Airplane mode or rebooting the device.

For 2g scenario I am setting NETWORK_MODE_GSM_ONLY by setting networkmode to '1'. But still whenever I select 2G, It shows 'E' in the status bar icon and changes to '3G' in just 1 or 2 seconds.

```
mTelephonyManager.setPreferredNetworkType(mSubId, 1);
Settings.Global.putInt(mContext.getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.PREFERRED_NETWORK_MODE + mSubId, 1)
```

I even tried in phone settings on typing `*#*#4636#*#*`, selecting 'GSM only' there, then also the behavior is same. The behavior is same even after turning on/off Airplane mode or rebooting the device.

Please Let me know if anyone has seen any issue like this, and where i might be going wrong.

I tried this command "**adb shell settings list global | findstr preferred**" and below was the output

```
preferred_network_mode1=1
preferred_network_mode=9
```

I even tried from adb using "**adb shell settings put global preferred_network_mode 1**" but didn't help.
later the output was

```
preferred_network_mode1=1
preferred_network_mode=1
```

But there was no change in behavior.

Please help me in understanding why this issue is occuring and Kindly enlighten me with what is difference between preferred_network_mode, preferred_network_mode1 and preferred_network_mode2.